# ASP.NET Core 1.1 compiling with C# dynamic Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC and started a new ASP.NET Core project targeting the full .NET Framework.

This line of code will not compile.

```
 dynamic handler = _container.GetService(handlerType);

 if (handler == null) _logger.LogError("Can't find handler to handle " + cmd.GetType().Name);
```

I get the following error

```
CS0656  Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
```

After some Googling it looks like this is because I'm missing the Microsoft.CSharp Assembly. There are plenty of people who have stumbled into his issue but not seemingly with .NET Core 1.1.

So I did this `Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp` and got version 4.3.0. My project still won't build.

If I add an Assembly Reference to Microsoft.CSharp (the GAC'd version) then it Compiles and runs.

Is this a Bug? I would have expected the NuGet package to fix this?

Comment: This NuGet package is for targetting .NET Standard. For full framework the GAC'd version should be used. It's ok. But Visual Studio 2017 RC not adding this reference automatically is probably a bug.

Answer (score 42):

I faced this problem. I resolved this problem for me.
You must install `Microsoft.CSharp` library to your solution from nuget.

You can use **Package Manager Console** for install **Microsoft.CSharp**. For example If you want install Microsoft.CSharp 4.7.0 version, you must run this command on the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp -Version 4.7.0
```

Nuget link: [Microsoft.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/)

Comment: After installing you have to close the solution and re-open it for this to work

Comment: @ruben Thanks you for comment. But I just installed, I didn't re-open project

Answer (score 22):

Just add the reference of Microsoft.CSharp.dll and your error will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

There was a similar problem.
I wanted to create a NetStandartd 2.0 library for the NetFramework 4.6.2 environment that `uses a dynamic object` and got the error "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create". This error is caused by the absence `of the Microsoft.CSharp library`.
By `correcting .csproj` file I was able `to make the correct linking`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0;net462</TargetFramework>
    <DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard2.0</DependsOnNETStandard>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem when trying to implicitly casting type `dynamic` to `object`.

```
    var output = new Dictionary<string, object>(); // <- object
    foreach(var attribute in attributes)
    {
        var attr = attribute as IEntityAttribute<dynamic>; // <- dynamic
        if (attr != null)
        {
            output.Add(attr.GetType().Name, attr.Value);
        }
    }
    return output;
```